# Replace first occurrence in row

Tags: sql, regex, bash, sed

I'm trying to figure out how to replace the first occurrence of a match (search/replace) via `sed`. I want it line by line (which I think is the default with `sed`).

Here's my dataset:

```
(4320, 38, '101.1.168.192.in-addr.arpa', 'PTR', 'test1.example.com', 3600, NULL, 1377614683),
(4321, 38, '102.1.168.192.in-addr.arpa', 'PTR', 'test2.example.com', 3600, NULL, 1377614683),
(4322, 38, '103.1.168.192.in-addr.arpa', 'PTR', 'test3.example.com', 3600, NULL, 1377614683),
(4323, 38, '104.1.168.192.in-addr.arpa', 'PTR', 'test4.example.com', 3600, NULL, 1377614683),
```

This is just a snip – it's a huge list. I'd like to take out the first number, for each line, specifically find `([0-9],` with `(,`.  This is so that I can have this SQL statement assign and `auto_increment` value by default, since I'll be taking this dataset and importing it into a table (that could have conflicts with the `auto_increment` values).

Here's what I would like it to look like when done:

```
( , 38, '101.1.168.192.in-addr.arpa', 'PTR', 'test1.example.com', 3600, NULL, 1377614683),
( , 38, '102.1.168.192.in-addr.arpa', 'PTR', 'test2.example.com', 3600, NULL, 1377614683),
( , 38, '103.1.168.192.in-addr.arpa', 'PTR', 'test3.example.com', 3600, NULL, 1377614683),
( , 38, '104.1.168.192.in-addr.arpa', 'PTR', 'test4.example.com', 3600, NULL, 1377614683)
```

I believe that would work.  I've tried some `sed` commands, but they all seem to remove the whole match until the end of the line (since I am matching what I am matching, it basically removes each `[0-9].*,`).

Comment: Please post your commands what you tried

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try the below GNU sed command,

```
$ sed -r 's/^\([0-9]+/( /' file
( , 38, '101.1.168.192.in-addr.arpa', 'PTR', 'test1.example.com', 3600, NULL, 1377614683),
( , 38, '102.1.168.192.in-addr.arpa', 'PTR', 'test2.example.com', 3600, NULL, 1377614683),
( , 38, '103.1.168.192.in-addr.arpa', 'PTR', 'test3.example.com', 3600, NULL, 1377614683),
( , 38, '104.1.168.192.in-addr.arpa', 'PTR', 'test4.example.com', 3600, NULL, 1377614683),
```

Comment: I'd say ending `g` has nothing to do here, even if it shouldn't break command.

Comment: This worked great.  Thanks for this.  I ended up using this and then supplementally used to in a different form to change current specific numbers that I know I needed to reference inside the database. This allowed me to import about 400 SQL entries with very little execution time.  Really appreciate it.